# HealthCheck not working properly

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

The HealthChecks in the Google Console are not working properly. Initially it worked properly. But now it is not working and always the instances in the backend service are shown unhealthy. Same instance if I hit the same health check manually working fine. Could someone please help me out on this?

Comment: Are the instances returning a 200 HTTP response code? This is a requirement as stated at [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/health-checks#overview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine now. The problem is with the Path in the Health Check.

I previously installed the wordpress on DB and configured the image to LoadBalancer. So the health check path with "/" passed.

But now I haven't installed the wordpress on DB so the health check has to be done on the path "/wp-admin/install.php".

After the change in the path this is working fine.